# Djangos truncatewords in twig

Tags: php, django, symfony, twig

Django has a filter called `truncatewords`, and `truncatewords_html`, that [Truncates a string after a certain number of words.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) Is there a similar function / what is the best way to achieve the same thing in twig (symfony in the backend).

Twigs slice function is not what I'm looking for since it doesn't respect spaces / words.

Comment: Give sample input and your expected output. Many of django developers may not familiar with `Twigs`

Comment: slicing after splitting into words, then joining again might work, no?

Comment: For example "This is a sentence", you want to split it then join them again?

Comment: I assume Moritz wants to generate a teaser text, and doesn't want to clip words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [custom Twig Filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) that will use regex to get what you want:

```php
class TruncateWordsExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
             new TwigFilter('truncatewords', [$this, 'truncateWords']),
        ];
    }

    public function truncateWords($text, $maxWords)
    {
        $regex = '/((\w+)[\W\s]+){0,' . ($maxWords - 1) . '}(\w+)/';

        preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);

        return $matches[0] ?? '';
    }
}
```

The `truncatewords_html` will ba a bit more complicated, assuming that you wanna keep the HTML tags structure and truncate just words within it, but at least you have a starting point.